# Can I edit my question to be on topic or does it not belong here at all?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I have a question about my Network Engineering Stack Exchange post: [Test Docsis Transponder without CMTS?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/83958/test-docsis-transponder-without-cmts)

Hello, I thought my question was on topic and best suited for this group but I'm new here so if you could please help elaborate or point me in the right direction if I'm wrong. Thank you.

Was my question considered off topic because I asked for a product recommendation assuming my question was not answerable? If I remove that part will it be ok?

I am not asking questions about enterprise products to be repurposed residentially. The question is about testing enterprise products in a lab setting for full functionality to then be used in an enterprise setting again. The unit I'm asking about is an HFC outside plant status monitoring card with a DOCSIS coax port so I thought this was the right place to ask about it. I think maybe it is off topic because I was asking about a way to substitute an enterprise product (CMTS) with something that could be considered residential? I was only asking as a means to test another enterprise product so it can then be used in an enterprise network setting again. Maybe I worded the question awkwardly but I don't want to resubmit without making sure I am in the right place. If the question belongs somewhere else could anyone point me in the right direction to figure this out? Again, any insight is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I might have figured out my own answer reading other meta posts. Is it because I'm asking a way to circumvent an enterprise product (CMTS) breaking the ""hardware that has a paid support option (enterprise/provider class products, some small business class devices)"" even if it is to test a different enterprise product?

Comment: It has a lot to do with asking for product or resource recommendations, which are off-topic on most SE sites.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're mostly seeking product recommendations, you could likely try on [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).